# Calculate the measure of the missing angle without trigonometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, angle

This was from a question that was closed recently.

It says to find the measure of angle '$a$'. (answer: $60^\circ$)

[image: image of the problem]

The below is my attempt to solve the question.

[image: attempt to answer]

As you'll see I drew $\triangle DAC$ that is congruent to $\triangle CFD$.

And I drew $\triangle CGD$ congruent to $\triangle DBC$.

Also, I drew parallelogram $FGDI$.

But any of these weren't useful to solve find the measure of angle $a$.

I can find the value using trigonometry.

But sometimes trigonometry becomes boring so anyone in this community could help me to solve this question without using trigonometry?

Thank you.

Comment: @ACB No I marked angle CDF as 50 but it was written the place that belongs to angle BDF

Comment: @ACB Can you name the triangles

Comment: I think a scaled image will help. I see the angle you marked as 90 is not a right angle.

Comment: @ACB Thanks I will change the image to a clearer one

Comment: Can you prove that $BC$ is tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$? (This must be true by working backwards from the answer.) If we prove this, then finishing the problem from there is easy.

Comment: @Bometh, Regarding my answer, I hope you can (easily) prove that points B', A, D are collinear. If not, (or you have any other question), please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given: $\triangle ABC$ with $CE \perp AB$, $\angle ACE = 20^\circ$ and $\angle BCE = 10^\circ$. Also, there is a point $D$ on $CE$ extend such that $\angle CDA = 50^\circ$. The question asks us to find $\angle ABD$.

Here is a construction that works.

[image]

We choose a point $G$ on $CI$ extend such that $\angle ABG = 10^\circ$. Then $ACBG$ is cyclic and a quick angle chasing shows that $\angle CAG = \angle CBG = 90^\circ$. So $CG$ must be a diameter of the circumcircle of $ACBG$ and its midpoint $O$ is the circumcenter. That leads to $\triangle AOB$ being an equilateral triangle.

As $\angle ADC = 50^\circ$ and $\angle DCF = 10^\circ$, we see that $\angle AFB = \angle BAF = 40^\circ$. So $BF = AB = BO$.

Since $\angle OBC = 20^\circ$, we have $\angle OFB = \angle BOF = 10^\circ$

Then notice that $\triangle AOC \cong  \triangle OBF$ (by S-A-S)

So it follows that $AC = OF = CH$ and since $\angle GOF = \angle GCH = 30^\circ$, $OFHC$ is a parallelogram and we obtain that $\angle BFH = \angle BCO = 20^\circ$.

$\angle AHD = \angle DAH = 40^\circ$. As segment $BD$ subtends $40^\circ$ at point $H$ and $F$ on the same side of the segment, $BDFH$ is cyclic. That leads to $\angle BDH = \angle BFH = 20^\circ$.

Finally, $\angle ABD = \angle AHD + \angle BDH = 60^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you @Math Lover. Waited for a day to get this answer

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Bometh if I can think of an easier construction, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler solution.

Mirror $B$ across $AC$.

[image]

It is easy to verify the collinearity of points $B'$, $A$, $D$. Then notice that $\triangle CBB'$ is equilateral and $\triangle CB'D$ is isosceles. Therefore $CB'=BB'=DB'$ which implies $B'$ being the circumcentre of $\triangle CBD$. That gives $\angle CDB=\frac12\angle CB'B=30^\circ$ and hence $\angle ABD=60^\circ$.

$\square$

Comment: Nice solution. I knew there was an easier solution but did not occur to me at that time.

Comment: Thanks @MathLover. I was in this problem from the very beginning (indeed!) and yesterday I saw this problem again and this solution came to mind. (Reflecting $B$ over $AC$. Familiar letters, aren't they?) :)

Comment: That's the beauty of geometry - when you see it, you wonder how you missed it all this while :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the fact that the sum of interior angles of a quadrilateral is 360, and the sum of interior angles of a triangle is 180. Also, know that all the angles at that point E are 90 degrees. You can use the 180 degrees fact where you treat two triangles as 1 triangle. That is how you could find out the angle next to a is 80. You might have to set up all of these facts as a system of equations where you have a variable for each unknown angle. Then you could solve for a.

Comment: No, this doesn't work.